# How to manually create a menu item for a taxonomy term?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, navigation

We need to create menu items out of some taxonomy terms in D7.  Currently we do this manually by switching between taxonomy and menu administration pages.  That is, we:

1. In the vocabulary administration page, create a term.  Set the term's path.
2. In the menu administration page, create a menu item pointing to the path of the above term.

This can get quite tedious.  There are some ways to automate this but we still want to create menu items manually for the sake of flexibility.  For example, we need to create several menu trees from a single vocabulary.  Also, the terms that would get a menu item are more or less hand-picked in our case, so they may not be easily selected with a view.  Ideally we just need some way to simplify managing the menu item of a term.

It would be great if there is a "menu settings" tab when editing a term, just like the same tab you get when editing a node.  That way we could have a single interface to manage the term and the menu item it created.

[image: menu settings when editing a node]

I am wondering if there is already a module for this.

Comment: Yes, there is a module for that https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu_form

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a module for this, but what you can do is to create it via views. There are two ways I can see:

1. Install [Entityqueue](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityqueue).

> The Entityqueue module allows users to create queues of any entity
>   type. Each queue is implemented as an Entityreference field, that can
>   hold a single entity type.
>
> For instance you can create a queue of:
>
> - Nodes
> - Users
> - Taxonomy Terms

2. Install [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) and [Views Bulk Operations,](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) then add a bulk operation on the flag in the specific view's UI.

Make sure to cache your views for better performance.